# Is a way to echo translation string in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to translate text inside the button.

```
<?php
                   
                        if ($product->category_slug === 'bramy-przesuwne' || $product->category_slug === 'bramy-skrzydlowe' || $product->category_slug === 'furtki' || $product->category_slug === 'przesla') {
                            echo '
                                                              <button class="product-cart-button" id="btnOpenForm">
                                                                    <p>'. '@lang(WYCEŃ)' .'</p>
                                                                </button>
                                                           
                                                ';
                        }
                        ?>
```

but the result is just @lang(WYCEŃ) inside this button.
What should i do to receive the translation in right way?

Comment: `'@lang(WYCEŃ)'` is a string! Is that inside a `.blade` file?

Comment: If translated filename is string.php, then you can use this
__("string.WYCEŃ");

Comment: ``{{ __ ('messages.WYCEŃ') }}``

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help. The solution is

```
<button class="product-cart-button" id="btnOpenForm">
<p>'. __('string.WYCEŃ') .'</p></button>
```